# Migrating my flutter project to null safety - indicates versions opting in to null safety is not showing

Tags: flutter, migrating

I'm trying to Migrating my flutter project to null safety. For that I run **dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety** it gives only indicates versions without null safety support.

But in this article I can able to see `https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide` indicates versions opting in to null safety.

Please advise.

Comment: I cannot quite understand your question. Could you maybe rephrase? What is showing up and what did you expect to see instead?